# Test with Junit the KeyPressed

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, keypress

I have this code in Java:

```
    public class KeyboardListener implements KeyListener 
    {
        public void keyPressed(final KeyEvent the_event) {
             final int key = the_event.getKeyCode();

             if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP && game.my_snake_direction != 40)
             {
                game.my_snake_direction = key;
                game.moveSnake(KeyDirections.UP.getDirection());
             }
        // ...
```

And I'm trying to test the KeyPress, but I don't know how to create the event or the component in the test code. In my code I haven't any component. Should I to create a component in test code?

```
    @Test
    public void KeyPressTest() {

    KeyboardListener KL = new KeyboardListener();
    KeyEvent the_event; //=new KeyEvent(..fail component..);
    KL.KeyPressed(the_event); //here the_event isn't init
```

PS: sorry for my english.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the class [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)

Add this to your function:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WHATEVER);
```